# How can I resolve smarty function in php?

Tags: php, function, smarty

I'm hoping someone can point me to the right direction in this.

Lets say I store Smarty template in database. It can look like this:

```
{currentusername UserID="5"}
```

The currentusername is a custom function to get the username. All displays correctly when used in a template. But what if I wanted to get the resolved currentusername function in my php code?

Basically I would get the template from the database, resolve it through smarty and then used the currentusername further in the code.

Is that possible?

Edit so it can be better understood. I have a this piece of code:

```
require('smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;

$macro = '{currentusername UserID="5"}';

$resolvedmacro = ""; // this should contain the "Jerry";

function smarty_function_currentusername($params, &$smarty){
  $UserID = $params["UserID"];
  if ($UserID == 5){
    return "Jerry";
    }
  else{
    return "I dont know this guy";
    }
  }
```

Can I somehow resolve the $macro through smarty so the variable $resolvedmacro would contain the correct value?

Comment: Your primary function should be somewhere in your code, where you can use it in "php"; and your smarty function should call that function.

Comment: Why not have a generic "currentUserName" function that gets called by the Smarty function but also can be called from your code? That would be much, much cleaner.

Comment: please check the edit, I believe this will better explain what im trying to accomplish :-)

Comment: We all understood you correctly, your should read again what I and @Pekka웃 have wrote to you....

Comment: @Glavić The OP is not asking how to relate the Smarty and PHP together, they are asking if Smarty can be used as a "macro" mechanism. While there is a valid question as to why they have selected this approach, your comment doesn't actually offer an alternative.

Comment: @IMSoP: I understand the OP question, all I did is suggest the better solution. I think we should help people in the way to give them better solutions than the question they might ask. This is the perfect example of one. I would never put my login in smarty function, and then call smarty functions in my other logic. This is just "bad" IMO. But ok, I would never use smarty for templating also, but that is never-ending debate... ;)

Comment: Hi, my cms is not build in smarty functions :-) I merely use this as a macro engine for the editors of the pages served by my cms.

Comment: @Glavić I think you have misunderstood what the OP was trying to achieve (so did I at first). The example is massively simplified because it consists only of a single callback function, but if what the OP actually wants is for a field in the database to contain a string which might *include* special macros - e.g. a `greeting` property might be set to `'Hello {currentusername}!'` then this is a very reasonable use for a templating engine. (And not one that could be replaced with PHP alone, unless you fancy `eval`ing untrusted data!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty can render a string as though it was a template using the `string:` or `eval:` "resource types" - see [the documentation on String Template Resources](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl) for details.

You can then use [`$smarty->fetch()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl) to get the output of that "template" into a normal PHP variable:

```
require('smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;

$macro = '{currentusername UserID="5"}';

$resolvedmacro = $smarty->fetch('string:' . $macro);
```

There is a wider question of *why* you want to do this, and whether Smarty is the right tool for the job - for instance, if there are a limited number of callbacks possible, it might be over-complicating things to use Smarty to resolve them rather than just storing the name of the callback and its arguments and running it through a switch statement.

**Note:** The `string:` and `eval:` resource types were added in Smarty 3; if for some reason you need to use Smarty 2, you will need to write or find a [resource plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.resources.tpl) to do the same job. You could also write a resource plugin for either version which fetched a particular macro from the database and rendered it in one step; [the docs for Smarty 3 are here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.resources.tpl).

Comment: Hi, that works awesome. Might I ask why this should be bad practise? I want to use smarty as a php macro engine to my cms. You think I should find something else?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily bad practice; it's just that your simplified example doesn't show very clearly how you're going to use it. If you're thinking in terms of whole blocks of text content into which people can put macros at will, then this (or a custom resource plugin, see note appended to my answer) may be a very sensible approach.

Comment: The purpose is simple -> My modules have properties, I want editors to be able to write macros in those properties and then use it in code. Your answer is great, so thank you.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, and it does sound like a reasonable way to do it. Glad I could be of help :)